Issues with CORS and NTLM Authentication for SharePoint 2016 On-Premise REST API
I am encountering issues with configuring CORS and NTLM authentication for accessing SharePoint 2016 on-premise REST API from a different domain. Here is the detailed setup and the problems I am facing:
Environment:

SharePoint Version: SharePoint 2016 On-Premise
IIS Version: 10.0.x running on Windows Server 2016 Standard
Authentication Method: NTLM

Domains Involved:
Production site: https://shptest2.domain2.com
Database like site: https://shpdatabase.domain3.com
Objective:
I need to access lists on shpdatabase.domain3.com from a web application hosted on shptest2.domain2.com using SharePoint REST API.
Current web.config Configuration:
Here is the current web.config configuration on the shpdatabase.domain3.com server:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-MS-InvokeApp" value="1; RequireReadOnly" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="^(https?://(.*\.)?domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <fileExtensions>
          <clear />
        </fileExtensions>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <clear />
        </hiddenSegments>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <!-- Module configuration here -->
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Handler configuration here -->
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".exe" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

JavaScript Code Used for Testing:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SharePoint API Test</title>
    <script>
        async function getRemoteListItems() {
            const appWebUrl = 'https://shptest2.domain2.com';
            const hostWebUrl = 'https://shpdatabase.domain3.com';
            const url = `${appWebUrl}/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('test01')/items?$top=10&@target='${hostWebUrl}'`;

            try {
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                    },
                    credentials: 'include' // Allow sending cookies and NTLM authentication
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);

                const contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
                contentDiv.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>`;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            getRemoteListItems();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SharePoint API Test</h1>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Issues Encountered:

When using credentials: 'same-origin', I receive a 401 Unauthorized error.
When using credentials: 'include', I receive a 403 Forbidden error.

Additional Information:

NTLM authentication is correctly set up on IIS. (I think)
The user has full access to the list.
I installed the IIS CORS module, but when I added the CORS tags to the web.config, the server immediately returned a 500 Internal Server Error.
CORS configuration seems to be applied correctly as no CORS-related errors are observed.

Question:
How can I correctly configure the SharePoint REST API, IIS, and my application to handle CORS and NTLM authentication across different domains? Any help or insights into resolving the 401 and 403 errors would be greatly appreciated.

What happens when you just try to open that url in a new browser tab?

What kind of 500 error with IIS CORS module? 500.19 or 500.0?

Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 and 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@CBroe if you think to put my full api url to browser that shows me json as i want. API call is built ok.

When using credentials: 'include', can you see the credentials actually being sent, when you inspect the request details in the browser?
